# Vue, show all results when multiselects are empty (no filters in place means all results show)

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a vue app where I"m simply adding filters (using vue-multiselects) in order to filter out values in an html table.

It's working perfectly for me, as far as showing the correct results when I add filters in the dropdowns. However, if I have nothing selected, nothing shows( as expected)

I'd like to make it so that if all dropdowns are empty (or maybe all of my arrays for the dropdown values are empty -- shiftArray, areaArray, etc.) then all results would show. Basically, no filters means show everything.

So, since I have the filtering working, I'm hoping someone can help me with figuring out the best way to make everything show if there are no filters in place.

```js
var vm = 
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  props: { 

  },
  components: {Multiselect: window.VueMultiselect.default},
  data: {
    selectedOutput: '',
    selectedarea:[],
    selectedStores: [],
    selectedShift: [],
    selectedCategory: [],
    CategoryArray:[],
    ShiftArray: [],
    areaArray: [],
    StoreArray: [],
    shifts: [
      {id: 1, name: "First"},
      {id: 2, name: "Second"}
    ],
    categories: [
      {id: 1, name: "electronics"},
      {id: 1, name: "home"},
      {id: 1, name: "auto"},
    ],
    outputOptions: [
      {id:1, name: "Sold"},
      {id:2, name: "Purchased"}
    ],
    areas: [
        {value: 1, name: "East"},
        {value: 1, name: "West"},
    ],
    stores: [
        {value: 1, name: "One"},
        {value: 2, name: "Two"}
    ],
    dates: [ "2021-10-02", "2021-10-03", "2021-10-04"] ,
    workNumbers: [
        {
          "Adam": {
            "2021-10-02": {
              "name": "Adam",
              "title": "Manager",
              "shift": "First",
              "category": "electronics",
              "area" : "East",
              "store": "One",
              "sold": 140,
              "purchased": 15,
              "station": 42,
              "date": "2021-10-02"
            }
          },
          "Ben": {
            "2021-10-02": {
              "name": "Ben",
              "title": "Manager",
              "shift": "First",
              "category": "electronics",
              "area" : "East",
              "store": "One",
              "sold": 225,
              "purchased": 77,
              "station": 42,
              "date": "2021-10-02"
            }
          },
          "Suzie": {
            "2021-10-02": {
              "name": "Suzie",
              "title": "Manager",
              "shift": "Second",
              "category": "home",
              "area" : "West",
              "store": "Two",
              "sold": 124,
              "purchased": 55,
              "station": 42,
              "date": "2021-10-02"
            }
          },
          "Reg": {
            "2021-10-02": {
              "name": "Reg",
              "title": "Manager",
              "shift": "Second",
              "category": "home",
              "area" : "West",
              "store": "Two",
              "sold": 66,
              "purchased": 36,
              "station": 42,
              "date": "2021-10-02"
            }
          },
          "Kelly": {
            "2021-10-02": {
              "name": "Kelly",
              "title": "Manager",
              "shift": "Second",
              "category": "home",
              "area" : "West",
              "store": "Two",
              "sold": 55,
              "purchased": 2,
              "station": 42,
              "date": "2021-10-02"
            }
          },
        }
    ]
  },
  methods: {

    addShiftSelection(){
      console.log(this.selectedShift);
      this.selectedShift.forEach(fields => {
        if(this.ShiftArray.indexOf(fields.id) !== -1){
          console.log("This exists")
        }else{
          this.ShiftArray.push(fields.name);
        }
      });
      console.log(this.ShiftArray);
    },
    addareaSelection(){
      console.log(this.selectedarea);
      this.selectedarea.forEach(fields => {
        if(this.areaArray.indexOf(fields.name) !== -1){
          console.log("This exists")
        }else{
          this.areaArray.push(fields.name);
        }
      });
      console.log(this.areaArray);
    },
    addStoreSelection(){
      console.log(this.selectedStores);
      this.selectedStores.forEach(fields => {
        if(this.StoreArray.indexOf(fields.name) !== -1){
          console.log("This exists")
        }else{
          this.StoreArray.push(fields.name);
        }
      });
      console.log(this.StoreArray);
    },
    addCategorySelection(){
      console.log(this.selectedCategory);

      this.selectedCategory.forEach(fields => {
        if(this.CategoryArray.indexOf(fields.name) !== -1){
          console.log("This exists")
        }else{
          this.CategoryArray.push(fields.name);
        }
      });
      console.log(this.CategoryArray);
    },
    removeCategorySelection(value){
       const removeIndex = this.CategoryArray.findIndex(category => category === value.name)
       if (removeIndex === -1) return // means item not found
       this.CategoryArray.splice(removeIndex, 1)
    },
    removeShiftSelection(value){
       const removeIndex = this.ShiftArray.findIndex(shift => shift === value.name)
       if (removeIndex === -1) return // means item not found
       this.ShiftArray.splice(removeIndex, 1)
    },
    removeareaSelection(value){
       const removeIndex = this.areaArray.findIndex(area => area === value.name)
       if (removeIndex === -1) return // means item not found
       this.areaArray.splice(removeIndex, 1)
    },
    removeStoreSelection(value){
       const removeIndex = this.StoreArray.findIndex(store => store === value.name)
       if (removeIndex === -1) return // means item not found
       this.StoreArray.splice(removeIndex, 1)
    },
  },
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-multiselect@2.1.0"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/vue-multiselect@2.1.0/dist/vue-multiselect.min.css">


<div id="app">

<div class="uk-width-2-10" style="position: relative !important;">
    <!-- <label for="output">Cubes/Pieces:</label> -->
    <multiselect
      v-model="selectedOutput"
      :options="outputOptions"
      :multiple="false"
      :close-on-select="true"
      label="name"
      track-by="name"
      :selected="Sold"
    ></multiselect>
</div>
<div class="uk-width-2-10" style="position:relative;">
    <multiselect
      v-model="selectedShift"
      :options="shifts"
      :multiple="true"
      :close-on-select="true"
      placeholder="All Shifts"
      label="name"
      track-by="name"
      @input="addShiftSelection"
      @remove="removeShiftSelection"
    ></multiselect>
</div>
<div class="uk-width-2-10" style="position: relative !important;">
    <multiselect
      v-model="selectedarea"
      :options="areas"
      :multiple="true"
      :close-on-select="true"
      placeholder="All Areas"
      label="name"
      track-by="id"
      @input="addareaSelection"
      @remove="removeareaSelection"
    ></multiselect>
</div>
<div class="uk-width-2-10" style="position: relative !important;">
    <multiselect
      v-model="selectedStores"
      :options="stores"
      :multiple="true"
      :close-on-select="true"
      placeholder="All Stores"
      label="name"
      track-by="name"
      @input="addStoreSelection"
      @remove="removeStoreSelection"
    ></multiselect>
</div>
<div class="uk-width-2-10" style="position: relative !important;">
    <multiselect
      v-model="selectedCategory"
      :options="categories"
      :multiple="true"
      :close-on-select="true"
      placeholder="All Categories"
      label="name"
      track-by="name"
      @input="addCategorySelection"
      @remove="removeCategorySelection"
    ></multiselect>
</div>


<table>
<tbody>
 <tr v-for="(value, employee) in workNumbers" :key="employee">
  <!-- Value will be dates object-->
  <td v-for="date in dates" :key="date" >
    <div v-for="(dateSpecificData, dateValue) in value.dates" :key="dateValue">
      <div v-if="dateValue == date ">
        @{{dateSpecificData.sold}}
      </div>
    </div>
  </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>

</div>
```

Comment: https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/conditional.html#conditional-groups-with-v-if-on-template i would add a to the templet an <v-else> which shows when no filters are selected.

Comment: Your code snippet does not actually render the table. And it refers to an undefined variable. Can you update it to show a working example?